# Algorithm For Intesection of Logical Expressions?

Tags: algorithm, math, logic, boolean-logic

Given a set of n elements `U`, and a set of m properties `P` where each element of P defines a function from U to boolean.

Given two composite logical expressions of the form (recursively defined):

```
p1 : true iff p1(x) is true
e1 and e2 : means e1 and e2 are both true
e1 or e2 : means e1 and e2 are not both false
not e1 : true iff e1 is false
(e1) : true iff e1
```

These logical expressions are parsed into expression statements (parse trees).

Assume that for any p1, p2: All four sets (p1 and p2), (p1 and not p2), (not p1 and p2), (not p1 and not p2), are non-empty.

I want to determine if a logical expression L1 is a subset of L2.  That is for every element x in U, if L1(x) is true then L2(x) is true.

So for example:

```
is_subset(not not p1, p1) is true
is_subset(p1, p2) is false
is_subset(p1 and p2 and p3, (p1 and p2) or p3) is true
```

I think I need to "normalize" the parse trees somehow and then compare them.  Can anyone outline an approach or sketch an architecture?

Comment: Sorry this is not related to your question, but I was wondering: what language would you recommend for programming formal logic?

Comment: @QuietThud: Prolog is the most common logic teaching language.  In the field we borrow logic programming "patterns" learned from logic programming languages, but implement them as library features in industrial languages like C++.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: I felt that there might be a solution to this problem using something similar to [Unification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) but it might require some tinkering. Thought of pointing to it just in case.

Comment: No, you don't need unification, because the objects `x` don't have any structure, they are not used in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't do anything with the objects (x) it seems you want propositional logic, where all combinations of the truth values for `p1` to `pn` are possible.

So essentially you want to do theorem proving in propositional logic.

Your `is_subset(e1,e2)` translates to a logical operator `e1 implies e2`, which is the same as `not e1 or e2`. To know if these hold universally you can check if the negation is unsatisfiable with an algorithm for satisfiability checking such as [DPLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm).

This is just a starting point, there are many other options to prove theorems in propositional logic.

Comment: This is an interesting idea.  I could synthesize `L3` as `(not (L1)) and (L2)`, and then determine if L3 is empty.  I would have to search for transformations like `X and not X -> false` and `X and X -> X` on L3 to try to make it resolve to false.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert each formula to the [disjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) and find if one contains a subset of the conjunctive clauses in the other. The complexity of this approach grows as the exponent of the number of pn mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think your instructor essentially wants you to implement the [Quine-McCluskey Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm)  Note that as the other answer implies, the execution time grows exceptionally fast because the problem is-NP Hard.